# How to rename file name in a folder adding more details at the end of the file names

Tags: vba

Original File Name is:  APAC Boss_Apr2015

I want to change file name to:  APAC Boss_GBSOL_YYYYMMDD

And also remove space in between. I cannot write any codes

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. StackOverflow is not a code-writing service, but we do help others debug their own code. Please read the help topic on [How To Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), then update your question with your VBA code.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim suffix As String, prefix As String, strRest As String
Dim strMiddle As String, ar() As String

suffix = format(Date,"yyyy") & format(date,"mm") & format(date,"dd")
ar = split(original," ")
prefix = ar(lbound(ar))
strRest = ar(ubound(ar))
ar = split(strRest,"_")
strMiddle = ar(LBound(ar))
Result = prefix & strMiddle & suffix
```